# Python, find out that a list does not have specific item

Tags: python, if-statement

Let's say there is a list a that contains both numbers and letters. Is there quick way to find out that the list doesn't contain some specific element. I plan to use it in conditions.

Answer (score 27):

Maybe

```
3 not in [1, 2, "a"]
# True
```

Comment: @A A: The OP asked for checking if an element is in a list.  Most probably that list won't be hard-coded in his code.

Answer (score 3):

Note: If you can put the elements as keys of a dict then testing for membership is much quicker thanks to the hashing algorithm. Will only be an issue if your list is very long or your app does a lot of this kind of thing. Otherwise, "X not in Y" as Sven says.

Comment: You could also use a set in this case.

Comment: You *should* use a set if you have no use for the dict values.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If speed does not matter, then use a in lst. If it does matter, it will depend on whether you can afford converting your list to a different data structure first (i.e. will you often look for items in the say list), size, etc...

To give an idea:

```
import timeit

a = range(10000)
da = dict(zip(a, [None for i in a]))

def list_first():
    return 0 in a

def dict_first():
    return 0 in da

def list_last():
    return 9999 in a

def dict_last():
    return 9999 in da

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in ["list_first", "dict_first", "list_last", "dict_last"]:
        t = timeit.Timer("%s()" % f, setup="from __main__ import %s" % f)
        print min(t.repeat(number=10000))
```

This gives me:

```
0.00302004814148
0.00318598747253
4.21943712234
0.004145860672
```

If you look for an item which is at the beginning of the list, using a dict does not speed things up, as expected. If you look for an item at the end, then the difference is very significant (3 order of magnitude), although as expected: dict use hashtable, lists needs to look for each item one after the other.

If items are comparable, you can also get a significant speed up by sorting your sequence and using a binary search (log(N) instead of N, log(N) being relatively fast compared O(1) for N not too big in practice for python), or using more advanced structures (binary search tree, etc...). It can get pretty complex - data structures for fast search is one of the most studied problem in CS after all.

Comment: Here is a more concise version of your code using sets instead of dicts: https://gist.github.com/742056.  Especially your constructor call to `timeit.Timer` seems a bit verbose :)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
bool([x for x in alist if isinstance(x, int)])
```

better version (by Sven Marnach):

```
any(isinstance(x, int) for x in alist)
```

?

Comment: If this really is what the OP wants, it would be better to write it as `any(isinstance(x, int) for x in alist)`, because this is more concise and stops iterating on the first int found.  But I don't think this is what is asked for.